# How to install latest JMeter in Ubuntu 15.10?

Tags: ubuntu, jmeter

When I try to install Apache JMeter in Ubuntu 15.10 using apt-get install JMeter it installs the older version 2.11. However, I tried to download the latest JMeter 3.0 version and when tried to run `jmeter.jar` file it won't open.

I am trying to install this on a Ubuntu 15.10 server. I can't upgrade to the latest version.

Could anyone guide me how to install or open the latest release of JMeter in Ubuntu 15.10?

Comment: In case of this error: `An error occurred: Assistive Technology not found: org.GNOME.Accessibility.AtkWrapper` , install  `sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre` instead of `jre-headless`

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Looking into [jmeter package details](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=jmeter) you won't be able to get latest JMeter via apt.

Follow the next simple installation steps:

1. `sudo apt-get update` - to refresh packages metadata
2. `sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre-headless` - Java 7 is pre-requisite for JMeter 3.0
3. `wget -c http://ftp.ps.pl/pub/apache//jmeter/binaries/apache-jmeter-3.0.tgz` - download JMeter 3.0
4. `tar -xf apache-jmeter-3.0.tgz` - unpack JMeter
5. `apache-jmeter-3.0/bin/./jmeter -n -t apache-jmeter-3.0/extras/Test.jmx` - run a sample test

If anything goes wrong check `java -version` command output, it should print something like:

> ubuntu@ip-172-31-57-21:~$ java -version
>
> java version "**1.7**.0_101"
>
> OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.6) (7u101-2.6.6-0ubuntu0.14.04.1)
>
> OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.95-b01, mixed mode)

Make sure you have **1.7** or higher.

Just in case see [How to Get Started With JMeter: Part 1 - Installation & Test Plans](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-get-started-jmeter-part-1-installation-test-plans) article for more detailed installation details

Comment: What about java 8 ?

Comment: How to pass "JVM_ARGS" argument using above command line to run jmeter?

Comment: Just like normal Linux environment variable, i.e. `export JVM_ARGS=foo`

Comment: latest jmeter can be downloaded here: https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi

Answer (score 15):

1. You can download `JMeter` from [here](http://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi).
2. In `Apache JMeter 3.0 (Requires Java 7 or later)` download the "
   apache-jmeter-3.0.tgz" package under the `Binaries` section.
3. Go to the Downloads directory and run `tar -xf apache-jmeter-3.0.tgz`
4. Run `cd apache-jmeter-3.0`
5. Run `./bin/jmeter` or `./bin/jmeter -?` for help.

Note: Make sure that you have 
JAVA installed and the JAVA_HOME environment variable is set.

Comment: Worked without any hiccups on Ubuntu 18.04. Thanks :D

Answer (score 3):

1.Download Jmeter(tgz format) from http://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi under binaries section.

2.Unzip the folder by running
`tar -xf apache-jmeter-4.0.tgz`

3.Run the following command to open JMeter
`./bin/jmeter`

Answer (score 1):

For Apache JMeter 5.1.1 follow the same instructions as suggested by others but these

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre-headless

wget -c https://www-eu.apache.org/dist//jmeter/binaries/apache-jmeter-5.1.1.tgz
```