# Phantomjs conversion error com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException:

Tags: jmeter, phantomjs

I've created a jmeter load test using phantomjs and I've run it locally without issues. When I place the test on an EC2 the test fails every time. I've looked around on the internet and tried all the suggestions that I could find, but no luck so far. I'm 100% sure that the "jmeter-plugins-webdriver-1.4.0.jar" is in the jmeter/lib/ext folder. I've ensured that my EC2 contains all of the dependencies that Phantomjs, and Jmeter require to run. The EC2 does not have a gui. Any help would be appreciated.

```
    jmeter -n -t 1joinOnly.jmx -l error101.jtl
    Error in NonGUIDriver java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Problem loading XML from:'/home/ubuntu/jmeter-bootstrap/bin/apache-jmeter-3.0/bin/1joinOnly.jmx', conversion error com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: 
    ---- Debugging information ----
    cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException
    cause-message       : 
    first-jmeter-class  : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter.unmarshal(HashTreeConverter.java:67)
    class               : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapper
    required-type       : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
    converter-type      : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapperConverter
    path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree/com.blazemeter.jmeter.webdriver.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverConfig
    line number         : 60
    version             : 2.13.20161028
```

-------------------------------

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to install the missing plugins via the Plugins Manager Command line. https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManagerAutomated/

Answer (score 0):

What jar? In what folder?

The error clearly indicates missing [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverTutorial/) plugin so my expectations are (NB: below instructions are applicable to Debian Linux and derivatives, the commands and paths might be different for other Linux distributions):

- you installed JMeter using `apt` package manager
- you put Selenium and WebDriver Sampler libraries to wrong folders

  - Selenium libraries should go to `/usr/share/jmeter/lib`
  - WebDriver libraries should go to `/usr/share/jmeter/lib/ext`

    (NB: I don't have Ubuntu nearby so the folders might differ, please double check them using [dpkg-query](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dpkg-query.1.html) command like `dpkg-query -L jmeter | grep lib`)
- you didn't restart JMeter to pick the .jars up

---

My recommendation is to switch to latest JMeter version from the one which comes with Debian (or Ubuntu):

1. Install latest version of JDK (not less than JDK 8)
2. Install latest version of JMeter (3.2 as of now) by downloading the tarball and unpacking it somewhere to your local file system. See [How to install latest jmeter in Ubuntu 15.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37333339/how-to-install-latest-jmeter-in-ubuntu-15-10) answers and comments if you need detailed steps
3. Install [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)
4. Install Selenium/WebDriver Support package using the Plugins Manager

   [image: JMeter Plugins Manager Selenium]

Comment: Hello Dmitri, 
Thank you for your answer. To answer your questions I have the jmeter-plugins-webdriver-1.4.0.jar in the lib/ext folder. Also I have the selenium jars in the lib folder. 
I'm running on an EC2 that doesn't have an gui interface so I'm not able to restart jmeter to pick up the jars. Is there a way to for jmeter to pick up the jars through the terminal?